# After upgrading (!?) to Ubuntu 20.04.3 Workspaces effects only one (of two) monitors

Tags: workspaces, workspace-switcher

I'm a happy user of Workspaces.

I upgraded to Ubuntu 20.04.3 and appear to have broken Workspaces.

I have 2 monitors.

When I click "Activities" or , I enter the Workspaces switcher. I have (only ever) seen one of the screens thumbnailed but I have always (until the upgrade) been able to switch between Workspaces that comprise Windows that span both (2) virtual screens, i.e. when I switch between Workspaces, even though only one screen is thumbnailed, I moved between Workspaces that comprise windows across 2 screens.

Since the upgrade (!?), when I switch Workspaces, one of the windows|screens remains unchanged while the other continues to let me switch between Workspaces.

It as if Workspaces (now understandably) accepts that, because I have 2 actual screens that I may wish to switch Workspaces between each independently.

However, I now (appear to) have no way to switch Workspaces on one of the physical screens.

Ideally I'd like to (return to what I had previously and) have Workspaces treat my 2 physical screens as a single Workspace that comprises 2 virtual screens. Alternatively, I'd like to be able to switch Workspaces on either screen independently.

Answer (score 0):

Solved!

I installed [`gnome-tweaks`](https://wiki.gnome.org/action/show/Apps/Tweaks?action=show&redirect=Apps%2FGnomeTweakTool)

Then, form "Workspaces", I selected "Worksapces span displays".

[image: Tweaks: Workspaces]